# Web Scraping in R (rvest, RSelenium): How to Authenticate into a Website that Requires a SSL Certificate

Tags: r, ssl, web-scraping, rvest, rselenium

I am new to web scraping and am seeking advice as to how I may successfully log into a website that requires a SSL certificate, using R. I have seen some posts on the topic for Python users but was unable to find an applicable solution for R.

For context, I have a valid SSL certificate to the website. When I manually open up my Google Chrome browser, once I have entered my login credentials, I am able to successfully login to the desired website. Sometimes, when the website login page has just finished loading in my Google Chrome browser, a Windows Security dialog box will appear , requesting that I "confirm the certificate".

I have tried authenticating into the website using RSelenium and rvest.

1. I first tried accessing the website with RSelenium + Docker. Here is my code using RSelenium, with specific information redacted:

```
# Actual constants not defined as they are/ require web authentication credentials 
# ADDRESS: (a string) IP ADDRESS 
# WEBSITE: (a string) a url to a https website
# USERNAME: (a string) the username used to log in to the website 
# PASSWORD: (a string) the password used to log in to the website

library(RSelenium)
remDr <- remoteDriver(
  remoteServerAddr = ADDRESS,
  port = 4444L,
  browserName = "chrome"
)

remDr$open()
remDr$navigate(WEBSITE)
webElement_username <- remDr$findElement(using = 'id', "textInput")
webElement_username$sendKeysToElement(list(USERNAME))
webElement_password <- remDr$findElement(using = 'id', "passInput")
webElement_password$sendKeysToElement(list(PASSWORD))
webElement_signinbutton <- remDr$findElement(using = 'name', "EnterClicked")
webElement_signinbutton$clickElement()
```

I encounter no error messages when running the code in R. However, when I call `remDr$screenshot(display = TRUE)`, I see that R has inputted my username and password credentials as designated, but R was not able to actually authenticate into the website as expected. (I do not believe that there is an issue with the code used to "click" the enter button to login to the website.)

2. Thinking that there may be an issue with trying to access the website with RSelenium + Docker, I tried accessing the website with rvest. Here is my code using rvest, with specific information redacted:

```
# Actual constants not defined as they are/ require web authentication credentials 

# WEBSITE: (a string) a url to a https website
# USERNAME: (a string) the username used to log in to the website 
# PASSWORD: (a string) the password used to log in to the website

library(rvest)
login <- WEBSITE

session <- html_session(login)
form <- html_form(session)[[1]]
filled_form <- set_values(form, UserName = USERNAME, Password = PASSWORD) 
logged_in <- submit_form(session, filled_form)
```

The rvest code runs with no error messages; however, when I call `browseURL(logged_in$url)`, a Google Chrome browser opens to the website login page, with my designated authentication credentials inputted. Sometimes, calling `browseURL(logged_in$url)` opens a Google Chrome browser to the website login page with the credentials inputted and a Windows Security dialog box, requesting that I confirm the certificate. Either way, my current rvest code is unable to login to my desired website.

I would appreciate any leads as to how I may be able to deal with SSL certificates when accessing https websites in R.

Thank you!

Edit: I added some additional comments to the sample code to explain what some of the defined constants are. The primary reference I used to write the code is from [Web Scraping Reference: Cheat Sheet for Web Scraping using R](https://github.com/yusuzech/r-web-scraping-cheat-sheet)

Comment: can you post the complete code for reproducibility or a minimum working example for others to replicate the problem?

Comment: Hello @mnm, I added some additional comments to the sample code to provide clarification as to what the defined constants are. The only part of my code that I did not provide is where I define the strings: ADDRESS, WEBSITE, USERNAME, and PASSWORD.  If it helps, the primary reference I used to write the code is https://github.com/yusuzech/r-web-scraping-cheat-sheet.